# Can setters be triggered in a parent class when a contained child instance is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two classes, A and B.

Instance A presents some of the properties of instance B to the UI. A is bound to the UI, B is not.

Is there any mechanism by which replacing the instance B will automatically call the setters in its container class A so that instance A can update the UI?

(Google is of no help. For complete source code, please see my previous question. [Last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229863/difficulty-updating-ui-when-contents-of-observablecollection-is-changed)).

Edit #1: To be more clear:

```
ObservableCollection<A> seeme;

class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private DATA B

   public string Something
  { 
     get { return B.something; }
     set { 
             if (B.something == value) return ;
             B.something = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Something");
          }
   }
}
```

Now A does:

```
 B = new B;
```

How to trigger the update for "Something" in A so the UI can be updated?

TIA

Comment: You really need to post your code here, or at the very least include a link to your previous question.

Comment: @juharr Sorry...Please see edit. (I can understand the downvote. I fixed it :) ).

Comment: who will replace instance B? If A is responsible for this, it already knows that B was replaced  and can raise property changed events after that. I think your question is still unclear, that why you didn't get any answers.

Comment: @AntonS Instance A is a member of an ObservableCollection and is being used to display properties downloaded from WCF, instance B being the raw data. Yes..A does replace instance B, but the UI is listening to changes in A--not B. Hence, is there a way for the setters in A to be automatically launched when A replaces B?  Thanks.

Comment: @juharr  Would it be possible to get an upvote so more people could see this question? Thanks. :)

Comment: @AlanWayne I didn't down vote if that's what you mean.

Comment: @juharr Sorry... Please see new edit if it helps any. Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest way is to call OnPropertyChanged("Something"); after B = new B(). You will have to do this for all properties. To make it more generic you can create [RefreshAttribute] and call method which will go through all properties with this attribute and call OnPropertyChanged(property.Name);

Comment: See my answer below - I added the implementation of my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

```
private DATA _B;
private DATA B
  { 
     get { return _B; }
     set { 
             _B = value
             OnPropertyChanged("B");
             OnPropertyChanged("Something");
          }
   }
}
```

This should be all that you need to get the UI Updated as you specified.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @ B is not tracked by the UI; only A is. There is no explicit binding to B...Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

to explain what I said in comments

> I think the easiest way is to call OnPropertyChanged("Something");
>   after B = new B(). You will have to do this for all properties. To
>   make it more generic you can create [RefreshAttribute] and call method
>   which will go through all properties with this attribute and call
>   OnPropertyChanged(property.Name);

1) Sets DataContractObject which is B instance

```
private DataContractObject _B;
public DataContractObject B
{
    get {return _B;}
    set {
           if (_B == value) return;
            _B = value;
           OnPorpertyChange("B")
           // refreshes all properties
           Refresh();
        }
}
```

2) Adds "RefreshProperty" attribute for all properties which have to be updated

```
[RefreshProperty]
public string Something1
{ 
 get { return B.something1; }
 set { 
         if (B.something1 == value) return ;
         B.something1 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Something1");
      }
 }

[RefreshProperty]
public string Something2
{ 
 get { return B.something2; }
 set { 
         if (B.something2 == value) return ;
         B.something2 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Something2");
      }
 }
```

3) Add refresh method (It's scratch of the method, maybe you will need to add some checks)

```
private void Refresh()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {

                    if (property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RefreshPropertyAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                    {
                        OnPropertyChanged(property.Name)
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since class A is aware of its own members and properties, it can raise `PropertyChanged` on any property it wants when B is changed internally. Since you're routing your properties to DATA b, then you need to let the UI know when all those routed properties have changed.

```
// Use this method to update your DATA
private void UpdateB(DATA newB)
{
    _b = newB;
    OnPropertyChanged("Something");
    OnPropertyChanged("SomethingElse") // if you have more properties
}
```

Comment: This still requires essentially listing all the properties manually--anyway to cause this automatically when _b is changed?

Comment: You don't want to do it automatically. That's reflection and binding overkill. Only notify the UI of what actually changed. That's just me. I find it proper to be explicit.

Comment: Except there will be many properties--some of which will not be known until a later date as they are downloaded from WCF.

Comment: If you're designing your UI so that it prints a collection of properties, for example (first name, last name, etc), and you want to allow the data to immediately appear if its structure changes, that is, the WCF service adds "Birthday" as a property, then you should probably take that information and plug it into an `ObservableCollection`. Otherwise, you're pretty much gonna have to create a new `TextBlock` to print the new Birthday value, which will need a Birthday {get;set;} property from your view model.

Comment: But this is up to you. It's up to the developer/designer to decide what's best. I prefer to control the UI as much as possible. I don't allow service data to dictate what appears on my client app. If they send a Birthday value, then I will redesign my UI to include a well-formatted output for the date and maybe include the age as well, and give it an appropriate location on the screen. But if you're printing raw text data, then go for it.